# Is it safe to delete logcat.txt files or the whole psysinfo folder to make more space on my Android phone?

Tags: internal-storage

I have an android phone and the space on the sdcard is getting scarce...
(I don't understand how android functions - just a simple user.)
In the following directory: `mnt > sdcard`

There is a `psysinfo folder`, which is 3.02 GB ...
And in this folder there are subfolders like log6, log5
and so on.
In these subfolders, there are a few logcat.txt files and three of them are like 1GB large.

Will my android phone function OK if I just delete these files and free some space (3.02 GB)?
I view the folders with 'ES File Explorer' and am thinking of deleting these files using the same app. This app says the above folder and logcat.txt files are the largest in my phone. My Android version is 4.1.2.

I searched online to find what the [ ...> psysinfo ] folder in Android is, but I couldn't find any info about it and then searched about deleting logcat.txt files but the info available seems to be for folks like developers. I couldn't really understand it.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a problem to delete them if there are only .txt or .log files. If you are not sure, delete a few files with smaller to medium sizes. Restart your phone, and check if all apps are working normally. If they are, then proceed with deleting the others.

Log files are used mainly for debugging purposes. Deleting them should not bring chaos onto your phone.